# why junk data receiving in Looper.getMainLooper())

Tags: android, user-interface, handler, presentation, android-looper

> Receiving proper data outside of **Looper.getMainLooper())**
>       I could not able to understand,why Junk data receiving inside of Looper.getMainLooper()).

```
 public class A1Service extends PresentationService implements
 Runnable {
 switch(dataId) {
      case 0x2b:
               Log.d("AAA", "speed_data==>" + speed  +"speed_id:--------"+ Data[0]);//here receiving properdata 

               new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).post(new Runnable() {
                          @Override
                          public void run() {
                           Log.d("AAA", "speed_data==>" + speed  +"speed_id:"+ Data[0]);//here receiving junk data         
                                }
                            });
                            break;
      case 0x40:
              new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).post(new Runnable() {
                          @Override
                           public void run() {
                           Log.d("AAA", "rpm_data==>" + rpm  +"id:--------"+ Data[0]);//here receiving junk data                                        
                                }
                            });
                            break;

   Logcat:
   speed_data==>537     speed_id:64
   speed_data==>17     speed_id:--------43
   speed_data==>538     speed_id:64
   speed_data==>18     speed_id:--------43
   speed_data==>1     speed_id:88
   speed_data==>19     speed_id:--------43
   speed_data==>1     speed_id:90
   speed_data==>20     speed_id:--------43
   speed_data==>1     speed_id:92
   speed_data==>21     speed_id:--------43
   speed_data==>25     speed_id:94
   speed_data==>22     speed_id:--------43
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My problem is resolved using AsyncTask.

like

```
private class CustomTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... param) {
            return null;
        }
        protected void onPostExecute(Void param) {
            case 0x2b:
           Log.d("AAA", "speed_data==>" + speed  +"speed_id:--------"+ Data[0]);//here receiving properdata 

           new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).post(new Runnable() {
                      @Override
                      public void run() {
                       Log.d("AAA", "speed_data==>" + speed  +"speed_id:"+ Data[0]);//here receiving junk data         
                            }
                        });
                        break;
  case 0x40:
          new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).post(new Runnable() {
                      @Override
                       public void run() {
                       Log.d("AAA", "rpm_data==>" + rpm  +"id:--------"+ Data[0]);//here receiving junk data                                        
                            }
                        });
                        break;
```